# Can rebuilt index take my site down

Tags: indexing, index

Some of my pages are not appearing in search results. I tried publish the page but that doesn't work. I think I need to rebuild the index. I am being cautious here, will my site go down until rebuild index is completed? If not how it will use index which is being rebuilt?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. For example: which version of Sitecore you are using?

Comment: Please provide more detail like-
1 Sitecore Version.
2 Which index you are re-building.
3 Logs . Being Time you can check following things.
1 Index configuration Included and exclude templates
2 Check publish queue table stat (https:// yoursitecorehost/sitecore/admin/PublishQueueStats.aspx) Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to avoid this to happen, you've to get the "zero downtime (switch on rebuild)" feature properly configured so a secondary index is created during the rebuild.

The steps to check/configure depend on which search provider do you have and Sitecore version.

For Azure Search Sitecore 8.2+ (except 10.2), check: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/zero-downtime-index-rebuild-in-azure-search.html

For Solr: https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/switch-solr-indexes.html

I hope it answers your question